# Check duplicate JID when connecting to XMPP

Tags: xmpp

I've got a private XMPP network that is just for automatic communication between components of a larger system. Every component connects with a unique JID, i.e. `<user>@<server>/<resource>`.

Sometimes it happens that a component doesn't shutdown properly and is still connected to the server. When that happens and I start a new instance, two clients with the same JID try to connect and they seem to play ping ping with the connection: the new one steals the connection from the old one, who then reconnects and steals the connection from the new one and so on.

Can I somehow check, whether the JID is connected **before** a components sends its presence? As I understand correctly, the server only sends the presences of other clients after receiving a presence, doesn't it? Just requesting the roster doesn't seem to help, because there is no presence information in there...

edit: I'm using SleekXMPP in Python, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

That "ping pong" happens when you use a fixed resource, which is something you shouldn't do. If your design depends on that, then you should reconsider it. Instead simply let the server assign a resource to you, or generate a random one on the client side.